# Redirect user if not logged

Tags: php

I want to redirect users to index page if they are not logged when they try to go directly to another page like "search or inbox. Now this is what I did but it keeps redirecting both logged and not-logged.

```
$u = "";
$isOwner = "no";
if($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true) {
     $isOwner = "yes";
}
if($isOwner != "yes") {
     header("location: index.php");
     exit();
}
```

What is the best approach to this?

Comment: Obviously, your `($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true)` doesn't fire.

Comment: We can't help you based on this code. Where are `$log_username` and `$user_ok` coming from? How are you authenticating users? You've omitted way too much for this to be answerable.

Comment: You probably want to add a `session_start()` somewhere to check wether user is connected or not...

Comment: Session_start() is at the beginning of every page..

Comment: Var u is set to nothing. I updated it now

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in to your application, you want to set a flag on the user's session stating he/she is properly authenticated and logged in. On subsequent requests, based on what the session variable says, you redirect your user to the login page or let the user continue further in your application. In very simple form, it would look like this.

In your login handler e.g. login.php,

```
if (authenticate($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) {
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
    # redirect to the main page
}
```

Now, on subsequent requests, early in your application, before invoking appropriate handlers,

```
if (empty($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
    # redirect to login page
}

# invoke handlers for the request
```

For this to work, you need to make sure the PHP session auto starts or start it manually using session_start() early in your application flow.

Answer (score 0):

I later tried this method and it works perfectly for me.

```
if($user_ok == true){}
else{
    header("location: login.php?u=".$_SESSION["username"]);
exit();
}
```

I just want to thank you all for your ideas.